# How to force drop room database if version number was unchanged and migration was unsuccessful

Tags: android, android-room

My app has local cache, stored in Room database, and data integrity isn't a priority to me at all, but what is the issue is a need to manually change version number each time, and it's hella annoying, especially during active development phase.

What I want — is simply delete a database and recreate it from scratch without worrying.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is creating an uncaught exception handler in the onCreate block and deleting database.

```
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler {  throwable ->
        if (throwable is IllegalStateException) {
            this.deleteDatabase("database-name.db")
        }
    }
```